# How to click on a link WebDriver 'Click' Method, Actions Class and JavascriptExecutor are not working?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="NarrowResultsSection">
   <div id="b_narrowClearAll"><span>Your Filter Selections</span> <a href="/search/everything?searchField=*&amp;category=everything&amp;searchFilter=" class="narrow-clear-all">Clear All</a></div>
   <div id="b_narrowClear">Books, Movies &amp; More<a href="/search/everything?searchField=*&amp;category=everything&amp;searchFilter=">Remove</a></div>
   <div id="b_narrowMedium">Medium: Books <a href="https://qa.qbpl.org/search/book?searchField=*&amp;category=book&amp;searchFilter=%20%20sm_format:book.audiobook">Remove</a></div>
   <div id="b_narrowMedium">Medium: Audiobooks <a href="https://qa.qbpl.org/search/book?searchField=*&amp;category=book&amp;searchFilter=%20sm_format:book%20">Remove</a></div>
</div>
```

Error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element
```

Comment: please share the code and xpath that you used.

Comment: Thanks @supputri    my code against the element was as ;  xpath here one type; WebElement audioBooks = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(text(),'Medium: Audiobooks ')]/a"));
           Actions builder= new Actions(driver);
           builder.moveToElement(audioBooks).click(audioBooks);
           builder.perform();
 and for JavascriptExecutor   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='b_narrowMedium"]/a'));
           JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
           executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Try with `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(text(),'Medium: Audiobooks ')]/a"));` and then `executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: Did already, it doesn't work.

Comment: `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(.)='Medium: Audiobooks')]/a"));` check with this element using js click.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `Medium: Audiobooks` use `WebdriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and then click the element.You can use following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='b_narrowMedium'][contains(.,'Medium: Audiobooks')]/a[contains(.,'Remove')]"))).click();
```